# Easier method to sorting which string is greater than using If Else Loops?

Tags: java

I was working on a program that lets a user enter three names and then sorts the names by which is greater, using .compareTo. The program works fine with the testing I have done but using If Else loops feels like a messy way to go about sorting the names. Was there an easier way for me to sort them?

```
//Determines if Name1 is greater than both other names.     
if ((name1.compareTo(name2) > 0) && (name1.compareTo(name3) > 0))  
{  
  //Determines if name1 or name3 is greater.  
  if (name2.compareTo(name3) > 0)  
    System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name1, name2, name3);  
  else   
    System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name1, name3, name2);  
}else if ((name2.compareTo(name1) > 0) && (name2.compareTo(name3) > 0))  //Determines if Name2 is greater than both other names. 
{  
 //Determines if name1 or name3 is greater.  
   if (name1.compareTo(name3) > 0)  
      System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name2, name1, name3);  
    else  
      System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name2, name3, name1);
}else if ((name3.compareTo(name1) > 0) && (name3.compareTo(name2) > 0))//Determines if Name3 is greater than both other names.   
{  
      //Determines if name1 or name2 is greater.  
   if (name1.compareTo(name2) > 0)   
      System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name3, name1, name2);  
    else   
      System.out.printf("%s\n" + "%s\n" + "%s\n", name3, name2, name1);
}
```

Comment: Use an array or `List`

Comment: Sort by which names character count is greater OR merely sort the names in Ascending or Descending order? Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways, using arrays:

```java
String name1 = "Allan";
String name2 = "Claudia";
String name3 = "Bianca";
String[] myArray = {name1, name2, name3};
Arrays.sort(myArray, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Now, your array is sorted. But, if you want just to print the names, you should use streams:

```java
Arrays.asList(name1, name2, name3)
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import java.util.Arrays;`.

Comment: You should use `forEach` to `peek` in this case. `peek` is used on consumed objects of the stream. The stream is not consumed yet, so nothing gets printed.